# Reactjs default Form validation with event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do not want to submit form clicking on submit. So i am using :

```
onSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }

<form className="loginform">
              <h1 className="logo"><img src={images.Logo} /></h1>
              <input
                className="login"
                placeholder="Username"
                type="text"
                required="true"
                onBlur={(e) => { this.userName(e); }}
              />
              <input className="login" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="true" />
              <input
                className="submit"
                onClick={(e) => { this.onSubmit(e); }}
                type="submit"
                value="Submit"
              />
            </form>
```

Doing so form validation is not working. I want to use default form validation with preventDefault.

Comment: Did you try using your method as a `onSubmit` property on your form instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use onsubmit form event:

```
<form className="loginform" onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
  <h1 className="logo"><img src={images.Logo} /></h1>
  <input
    className="login"
    placeholder="Username"
    type="text"
    required="true"
    onBlur={(e) => { this.userName(e); }}
  />
  <input className="login" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="true" />
  <input
    className="submit"
    type="submit"
    value="Submit"
  />
</form>
```

In general you should avoid handling form submission via button onclick events, additional benefit of onsubmit is that it will also be fired on ENTER key submission.